# Design pattern for dealing with reusage of date in scenarios (BDD)

Tags: selenium, design-patterns, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, bdd

I would like your suggestion for my scenario:

I am implementing automated tests using bdd technique with Cucumber and Selenium WebDriver tools, what is currently happening is: a lot of scenarios depend of data of each other, so right now I am storing these data in the class I define the steps, so I can use in other scenarios.

But, as the application grows, and the more scenario I get, the more mess my application gets.

Do you have any design pattern, or solution I could use in this case?

Comment: I would recommend keep your data outside in flat files / csv files / spreadsheet..so that while parallel testing if you need same data to be passed to different scenarios that would be much easy.

Answer (score 0):

Overall you want to be looking at a [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html).

At the Cucumber level have two 'layers' of responsibility, the Test Script (Feature File + Step Implementation) and model of the system under test.  The Step Implementation maps straight onto the model.  Its single purpose is binding feature steps to methods. The Model implementation is to model the state of the system under test which includes state persistence.  The model should expose its interface in the declarative style over the imperative approach such that we see `fooPage.login();` in preference to `page.click('login');`

On the Selenium WebDriver side of things use the [Page Objects Model](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects)  It is these reusable object that understand the semantics of representing page and would be a third layer.

**Layers**
 - Test Script (Feature File + Java Steps)
 - Model of SUT (which persists the state)
 - Page Object Model -> WebDriver/Browser

Answer (score 0):

As you say, scenarios that depends on data from other scenarios gets complicated and messy. The order of execution is important.

What would happen if you executed the scenarios in a random order? How would that affect you?

My approach would be to work hard on making each scenario independent of each other. If you have a flow like placing an order that is required for preparing a shipment that is required for creating an invoice and so in, then would I make sure sure that the state of the application was set correct before each scenario. That is, executing code that creates the desired state.

That was a complicated way to say that, in order to create an invoice I must first set the application state so that it has prepared a shipment. And possible other things as well.

I would work hard on setting the application to a known state before any scenario is executed. If that means cleaning the database, then I would do that. The goal would be to be able to execute each scenario in isolation.

The functionality in your system may build on each other. That doesn’t mean that the scenarios you use to check that your application still works should build on each other during their execution.

Not sure if this qualifies as a pattern, but it may be a direction to strive for.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, try to isolate test scenarios from each other regarding data.

Just a few approaches:

1. Either cleaning the database or restoring the original data before each test scenario is executed will make it; however, that can slow the tests down significantly. If the cleaning action takes around 10 seconds, that makes ~15 additional minutes for 100 tests, and ~3 hours for 1000 tests.
2. Alternatively, each test could generate and use its own data. The problem here is that many tests could really use the same data, in which case it makes little sense to create those data over and over again, let alone this is something that also takes time.
3. Yet another option is to tell between read-only tests and read-write tests. The former could make use of the default data, as they are not affected by data dependencies. The latter should deal with specific data to avoid running into conflicts with other test scenarios.

Still, step definitions within a test scenario are likely to depend on the state of the previous step definitions executed as part of that test scenario. So state management is still required somehow. You may need some helper Object in your Model.

Keep in mind that Steps classes are instantiated for every test scenario, along with the Objects created from them. Thus, private instance attributes won't work, unless all the steps used by a test scenario are implemented in the same Steps class. Otherwise think about static variables or try with a dependency injection framework.